A Local-Global principle for finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules
I am looking for counterexamples or reference for the following statement:
Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then $M$ is finitely generated if and only if
$M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module for all primes $p$. Here, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the $p$-adic ring. The implication $\Rightarrow$ is automatic. I am interested when (or counterexamples) the converse is true.

The backwards direction is false: there exist $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $M$ for which $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all prime $p$, but $M$ itself is not finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$.
Here's an example I learned from Brian Conrad's notes on Abelian Varieties (remark at the end of Section 4). Let $M = \sum_{p} \frac{1}{p} \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, where the sum is taken inside $\mathbb{Q}$ and ranges over all primes $p$. Then $M$ is not finitely generated as an abelian group since only finitely many prime factors can occur in the denominators of a finite set of rational numbers, and taking sums cannot produce new prime factors in denominators. However, $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p \simeq \frac{1}{p} \mathbb{Z}_p \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p$ is a rank $1$ free $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module for all prime $p$, which follows from the fact that any prime $q \neq p$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Thanks for this example!!!

The other answer is a counterexample to the converse using a torsion-free $\mathbf Z$-module.  Here is a counterexample using a torsion module.
Let $M$ be a torsion $\mathbf Z$-module. Then $M = \bigoplus_\ell M[\ell^\infty]$ where the direct sum runs over all primes $\ell$ and $M[\ell^\infty]$ is the submodule of elements of $\ell$-power order in $M$. Then
$$
\mathbf Z_p \otimes_{\mathbf Z} M = \mathbf Z_p \otimes \bigoplus_\ell M[\ell^\infty] = \bigoplus_\ell (\mathbf Z_p \otimes_{\mathbf Z} M[\ell^\infty]).
$$
When $\ell \not= p$, $\mathbf Z_p \otimes_{\mathbf Z} (M[\ell^\infty]) = 0$ since all elementary tensors there are $0$, as $\ell$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z_p$. Thus $\mathbf Z_p \otimes_{\mathbf Z} M = \mathbf Z_p \otimes (M[p^\infty])$, and $\mathbf Z_p \otimes_{\mathbf Z} (M[p^\infty]) \cong  M[p^\infty]$ using obvious maps in both directions.
Thus when $M$ is a torsion $\mathbf Z$-module such that $M$ is not finitely generated but $M[p^\infty]$ is finitely generated for each prime $p$, $M$ is a counterexample to the converse direction. A simple example of this is $M = \bigoplus_\ell \mathbf Z/\ell\mathbf Z$.
